# How to deal with duplicate line in BDD with Symfony 5 and multithreading?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

We made an app with Symfony 5 which explores website and links.
Each process will detect all a href inlinks and add them to URL database.
To increase performance we use multiple process.

Problem is we insert in database same URL multiple times despite a check if URL already exist; because some times, 2 or more process insert eh same URL after they all check and returned nothing.

We didn't manage to implement in doctrine an equivalent of the SQL INSERT on duplicate key update.
Can you enlighten us of which is the correct process to deal with this kind of problem?

We're going to add a duplicate check on each new process start but we'd like to know if it's the best practice of if we are missing something.

Answer (score 1):

what "database" are you using? If it's a RDBMS like MySQL it's not the best for this kind of work.

I recommend to switch to a key-value store, something like Redis, it's way more effective for this kind of work. Why? Because redis is single threaded and each operation are atomic. This means that while one command is executing, no other command will run. So you'll be sure than if the page url (key) don't exists, your app have never seen it before.

If you still want to stuck with MySQL, you need to implement lock to avoid multiple insert on same URL.
You can take a look at this documentation: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html

Also, you can (and you should) add a unique constraint on page url field. It's a best practice since you didn't want two times the same url in your table.